A question about the isomorphism between Grothendieck groups of representations categories
I have a question about the isomorphism between Grothendieck groups of representations categories.
If $A$, $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with the identity, we assume that  $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~A)$ is the Grothendieck group of the category of fnite-dimensional modules of $A$ and  $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod}~B)$ is the Grothendieck group of the category of fnite-dimensional modules of $B$.
Here is the question:
If there exits a group isomorphism $f$ from $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~A)$  to $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~B)$, does $f$ put the simple module class to the simple module class?
To be more precise, if I choose $[M]\in \mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~A)$  is a simple module class, then is $f([M])$  a simple module class which belongs to $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~B)$?
Here is my attempt:
Let $f([M])=[V]\in \mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~B)$.
Assume $[V]$ is not a simple module class which belongs to $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathrm{mod} ~B)$, we can assume that $[V]=[V_1]+[V_2]$ with $[V_1],[V_2]\ne 0$.
Then $[M]=f^{-1}([V])=f^{-1}[V_1]+f^{-1}[V_2]$ with $f^{-1}[V_1],f^{-1}[V_2]\ne 0$. This is
a contradiction since $[M]$ is a simple module class.
My question is whether the above proof is correct?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

No not necessarily:
$Rep(mod A)$ will just be $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as an abelian group where $n$ is the number of simple modules for $A$. Taking $B = A$, you have a full $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$'s worth of isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to itself, most of which do not preserve the standard basis.
The issue with your argument is you are assuming the isomorphisms (in both directions) are sending positive linear combinations of simples to positive linear combinations of simples, but the Grothendieck group has additive inverses so you need to consider arbitrary integral linear combinations (positive and negative).

Thank you. I realized I overlooked the negative  part.
